# Laravel post giving 500 (Internal Server Error) but not get method

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have the following which I used to call my ajax upon form submission

```
$.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "grades/ajaxGradePrice",
      data: { gradeID: $('#GradeID').val()}
  })
  .done(function( msg ) {
      alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

At my controller is this

```
public function ajaxGradePrice(){
      //$gradePrice=199;
      //return $gradePrice;
}
```

My route is this Route::post('grades/ajaxGradePrice', 'GradesController@ajaxGradePrice');

Eventually I get this 500 (Internal Server Error) but surprising when I change all the post to get its working perfectly fine that both the method:"GET" and `Route::get('grades/ajaxGradePrice', 'GradesController@ajaxGradePrice');`

Comment: Check your error logs, located in `/storage/logs`.

Comment: Nothing related to this error is generated there?

Comment: Do you have debugging turned on? If so go to the Network tab in Chrome you should be able to see the returned response in preview mode.

Comment: Aren't you forgetting a CSRF token or something? 500 usually means a PHP fatal error occurred.

Comment: Yes you are right I am getting this TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68: ?

Comment: But just below the form I have this  {{ csrf_field() }} ?

Comment: add "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}" in your data object, which you are passing with request

Comment: `{{ csrf_field() }}` is for a form submission not an ajax post

Comment: I dont get you where to add you mean this  data: { gradeID: $('#GradeID').val()}

Comment: Ok I just did this data: { gradeID: $('#GradeID').val(),"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}" } at it seems to be working.

Comment: Can some one add this as answer so that it will useful for next person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in comments up here; you're missing the CSRF token in your request.

Add the token to your Ajax POST:

```
{ gradeID: $('#GradeID').val(),
"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}" }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are forgetting the csrf token

In your data object which you are passing by ajax, just add **"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",**

Your data object should look like

```
 data: { gradeID: $('#GradeID').val(), "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"}
```